# Which bulb do I have to buy for 2011 Toyota Camry tail lights?

Tags: toyota, camry, tail-lights, bulbs

The car’s brake lights are working, but tail lights are not.
What is the model number for 2011 Toyota Camry tail light bulb?
And just curious, are the brake light and tail light bulbs same in this car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which model of Camry is this? ie: Hybrid; LE; SE; XLE?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a non-hybrid car (4-cyl or 6-cyl), the bulb part number should be a Philips 921 (see cross ref below). The bulbs are the same for both brake and tail light. If you have a hybrid, it's some other bulb (or bulb assembly) which isn't listed where I'm looking.

Here's actually a cross reference by manufacturer for you:

```
 ECE:     W16W
 GE:      921
 GM:      12450313
 Hella:   78652
 Osram:   921 (Sylvania)
 Philips: 921
 Wagner:  921
```